# Fixing keyboard layout on Xubuntu (can't use AltGr)

Tags: keyboard, xfce, xubuntu, xkb

I'm going crazy with my laptop's keyboard. My layout is latin spanish, and works just fine. However at some time of the morning some magic auto-reconfiguration makes my layout implode and I can't use AltGr, wich means I can't use backslashes, at symbols, newflos, etc.

[image: My keyboard layout]

By the way, I'm using Xubuntu 12.14, on a laptop. I have almost the same system configurated on my desktop pc and when madness strikes my keyboard, re-plugin it solves everything. Sadly, I don't have this cheap option on my laptop.

I was trying to remap AltGr with xmodmap, but it doesn't help.

**Any suggestions about how to fix this bug?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your keyboard-layout using setxkbmap, e.g.:

> setxkbmap -layout es

xmodmap shouldn't be necessary when using a standard-layout without any additional configuration.

Comment: I don't know if this will fix my problem forever, as it seems to be a periodical issue but will do for now. Got to have something to do with my messy collection of configuration files :|.

Comment: Just a little addendum, the keyboard shown on the picture is a *Spanish Latin America* so, try with `latam` instead of `es`